# I want to know how to use delays on a java project in eclipse to use drawing components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, project

I want to be able to use multiple drawing components with delays. when i am trying to use a delay the program will just stop and only display the first drawing component. with no delays only the second drawing component shows. Im trying to make an analog clock that changes an hour every 30 seconds and the scenery in the background will update. The first code is the main class the second one is drawing component 1 and the last one is the second drawing component. I would love some help.

```
//imports J Frame library
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Creates variable window
        JFrame window=new JFrame();
        //creates window 640 wide by 480 high
        window.setSize(640,480);
        //Sets a title for JFrame
        window.setTitle("This is a JFrame");
        //End program when window closed
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Sets JFrame window to be seen
        window.setVisible(true);
        //Create an instance of DrawingComponent
        DrawingComponent DC=new DrawingComponent();
        //Add DC to window
        window.add(DC);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
        //Create an instance of DrawingComponent
        DrawingComponent2 DC2=new DrawingComponent2();
        //Add DC to window
        window.add(DC2);


    }

}`

//an instance of JComponenet class drawing component 1
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
//import color library
import java.awt.Color;
//import font library
import java.awt.Font;
//imports graphics class
import java.awt.Graphics;
//imports 2D graphics class
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
//imports Rectangle class
import java.awt.Rectangle;
//imports 2D ellipse library
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
//imports 2D line library
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
//imports 2D Point library
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
//Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


//Created a class DrawComponenet needed to add extends JComponenet
public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent
{

    //implemented a method from JCompnent class
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
         g.drawOval(100,10,400,400);
         g.setColor(Color.white);
         g.fillOval(100,10,400,400);


    }

}


   /an instance of JComponenet class drawing component 2
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
//import color library
import java.awt.Color;
//import font library
import java.awt.Font;
//imports graphics class
import java.awt.Graphics;
//imports 2D graphics class
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
//imports Rectangle class
import java.awt.Rectangle;
//imports 2D ellipse library
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
//imports 2D line library
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
//imports 2D Point library
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;


//Created a class DrawComponenet needed to add extends JComponenet
public class DrawingComponent2 extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
     g.setColor(Color.orange);
     g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
     g.drawOval(100,10,400,400);
     g.setColor(Color.blue);
     g.fillOval(100,10,400,800);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not understand how Java swing works. There are multiple threads running in order to get key events, repainting each components,...

As I understand in your question and after see your code example, I recommend you to see how Java Swing with MVC pattern works here https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-swing-mvc-example/

After that, you should have to create a thread in your controller to change your component after 30 seconds.